# I can't run kivy on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I use :

```
python3 -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew --user
```

and

```
python3 -m pip install kivy[full] kivy_examples
```

Error log:

```
[←[1;32mINFO←[0m   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[←[1;31mCRITICAL←[0m] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or 
change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cgl_glew: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 982, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 289, in create_window
    self.get_gl_backend_name())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1228, 
in get_gl_backend_name
    return cgl_get_backend_name(
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 56, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 69, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module      
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1108, in create_module    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed  

[←[1;31mCRITICAL←[0m] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Was this the output from the kivy Hello World app?

Answer (score 0):

I found in warnings about `not in the PATH` for pygments.exe
I just added to env Path next value :

```
ABSOLUTE\kivy_venv\Scripts
```

uninstall and install it with pip3.9 and works !